# Metrics per collection on Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The firestore dashboard show global metrics for all operation on firestore (read, write, delete, etc...).

I was wondering, is it possible to see these metrics on a per collection basis?

It would be helpful to easily identify potential problems :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering, is it possible to see these metrics on a per collection basis?

No, this is currently not possible, [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage) you can find all the metrics available for Firestore. If you need some metrics related to a particular collection, you should create your own mechanism for that. There is no out of box solution in this case.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for a metrics system to use that would integrate well in the cloud platform environment?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of such metrics systems.